# Basic 2D Texture Howto for iPhone OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

Just started learning OpenGL and couldn't find a decent tutorial to get me going. Specifically, I'm looking for something that will show me how to load an image to an OpenGL texture, store it in a variable to display later, and then draw the image.

I'd appreciate it if someone could write out the basic code to do that for me. If I may ask that you would also separate the code for loading and drawing and also comment thoroughly as to whats going on.

Much obliged

Comment: You should consider using the search field at the top-right corner of each StackOverflow page. There are several questions about OpenGL tutorials with a focus on the iPhone, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+opengl 

Also, it's unlikely that people will take the time to write out hundreds of lines of code for you. If you're genuinely interested in this subject, you'll want to do a little research of your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been referring to this:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apple's ImageProcessing sample.